# How to polymerize repeating units of polymers into dimers

Tags: polymer, rdkit

I want to polymerize the repeating units of the polymer into dimers or trimers. The repeating units are represented by SMILES, such as

`*CCC(C)C(*)C`

The '*' represents the polymerize point, how can I get the dimers SMILES of this repeating units?

appreciate your help!

I tried looking for a solution to this problem in RDkit but didn't find any.

Comment: You should try `reaction SMARTS` in RDKit. 
[link1](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/RDKit_Book.html#chemical-reaction-handling) 
[link2](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html#chemical-reactions) 
[link3](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit-tutorials/blob/master/notebooks/003_SMARTS_ReactionsExamples.ipynb)